# How to add a link to the part of text passed to a react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have to display a list of items. Each list item will have an item name. I have to add a link to this item name which is passed as a prop to the component.

I pass this text to be displayed (item name and other details) to another component. However, how can I add a link only to item name separating it from the text prop passed.

Below is the code,

```
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    render = () => {
        switch (item.type) {
            case 'new_item_uploaded':
                return (
                    <Item
                        icon=<Svg/>
                        text={`${list_item.author.name} created item 
                        ${list_item.attributes.name}`}
                        timestamp={timestamp}
                    </Item>
                );
            case 'item_deleted':
                return (
                    <Item
                        icon=<Svg/>
                        text={`${list_item.author.name} deleted item 
                        ${list_item.attributes.name}`}
                        timestamp={timestamp}
                );
         } 
}

function Item(props) {
    return (
        <li className="notification">
            <div className="details">
                <div className="icon">
                    {props.icon}
                </div>
                <span>{props.text}</span>
                <Timestamp>{props.timestamp}</Timestamp>
            </div>
            {props.children}
        </li>
    );
}
```

What i want to do?

In the Item component for the text prop which contains {list_item.attributes.name} part should be a link. How can I do that?

I want to do something like this,

```
<Link to={`/some_url/${this.props.list_item.id}`}>i want to somehow to get 
the list_item.attributes.name here...</Link>
```

How can I do this???
Or any other way to achieve this...could someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass down the **id**, **authorName** and **name** data as separate props:

```
<Item
  icon=<Svg/>
  timestamp={timestamp}
  id={list_item.id}
  authorName={list_item.author.name}
  name={list_item.attributes.name}
</Item>
```

Then you can use those in your `Item` component to construct the text containing the `Link`:

```
<span>
  <Link to={`/some_url/${props.id}`}>{props.authorName}</Link> created item {props.name}
</span>
```

---

If the **text** prop needs to be different in other cases then you could pass the JSX down as the prop:

```
<Item
  icon=<Svg/>
  timestamp={timestamp}
  text={
    <span>
      <Link to={`/some_url/${list_item.id}`}>{list_item.author.name}</Link> created item {list_item.attributes.name}
    </span>
  }
</Item>
```

Then your `Item` component can just render `{props.text}`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks...but is there a way to retrieve the list_item.attributes.name from text prop and use it in link?

Comment: You could use regex but that seems like a bad idea. Why not construct the text inside the `Item` component using the data from the props rather than passing in the assembled text?

Comment: hmm this text differs for each item type...so passing the assembled text...but i am thinking how can i add a link to itemname within the text prop...

Comment: I have updated the answer to construct the text inside the `Item` component from the 3 pieces of data passed down as props.

Comment: thanks but this item component should also be reused for other listitem types...for example case. item uploaded has text created item...case item deleted has text item deleted. there are other cases as welll which have different text to b displayed for user.

Comment: I have now added this to my answer :)